# Size menu items based on how many there are in JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, menu, size

I need to have a menu that has items that size themselves based on how many there are. Say, there are three items. Each one would have about 33% width of the container. But if there were were ten, each would have 10%. Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually menu is built from unordered list and parent menu element have id="menu"
In this case you'll need code like next:

```
menuElt = document.getElementById('menu');
childElements = menuElt.getElementsByTagName("li");
var quantity = childElements.length;
var widthPercent = Math.round(100/quantity);
for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
  childElements[i].style.width = widthPercent + "%";
}
```

Comment: That, in chrome, just throws the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null. Oops, I think that might be an error caused by my fluent html5...