# Dynamic Size Menu Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new on java script and I have been trying to develop a select menu using java script and HTML. It has to change the size of how many items the select menu will show according to which button is press.
Is there a way to make it dynamically change the size?

Here is what I have so far.

```
var value = 6;
$("button").click(function() {value = $(this).val();});

var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = [];
for ( j = 1; j < value; j++){
        options += j.toString();
}
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Here is the HTML portion:

```
<button id="3" name="3" value="3">3</button>
<button id="4" name="4" value="4">4</button>
<button id="6" name="6" value="6">6</button>

<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size menu items based on how many there are in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988813/size-menu-items-based-on-how-many-there-are-in-js)